# Tablesorter jquery plugin fails in FF 3.6.12 with msg "table.config.parsers[c] is undefined"

Tags: jquery, macos, firefox, tablesorter

With the latest version of the plugin as of 5/4/2011 on OSX 10.6.7 w FF 3.6.12
Chrome, Safari, and IE all work perfectly fine.
I also tried it with FireBug disabled to no avail.

Here's the HTML I'm testing with:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang='en' xml:lang='en' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
          <head>
          <script src="/javascripts/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js?1301000558" type="text/javascript"></script>
          <script src="/javascripts/jquery.tablesorter.js?1304537000" type="text/javascript"></script>
          <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#testtable").tablesorter( {debug:true} );
        });
          </script>
          </head>

          <body>
                <table id='testtable'>
                <thead>
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>Col2</th>

                <th>Col3</th>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>val1</td>
                <td>val2</td>
                <td>val3</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>

                <td>val2</td>
                <td>val1</td>
                <td>val3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                <td>val3</td>

                <td>val1</td>
                <td>val2</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
          </body>

        </html>
```

---

With firebug on, here are the messages before trying to click on a column header:

```
Built headers:,0ms
[th.header, th.header, th.header]
Checking if value was empty on row:0
Checking if value was empty on row:0
Checking if value was empty on row:0
column:0 parser:text column:1 parser:text column:2 parser:text
Building cache for 3 rows:,0ms
```

Here's the errors after clicking:

```
    table.config.parsers[c] is undefined
```

which is in the setTimeout function around line 600 in the un-minified source.

Comment: THIS IS A NON-ISSUE.  I WAS MISSING A TR TAG AROUND THE TH TAGS.

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same issue, the problem was I was using empty `<TR>` which had `COLSPAN` in all the empty rows.
 When I removed the `<td colspan="3">` and did three empty `<TD>` the problem was gone.

Comment: Thanks @dBlaze, Your answer solves the issue i was facing with tablesorter, Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I ran into the same issue when inserting dynamic data into rows using PHP. The issue only occurred in IE. All I had to do was to silence the debug, like this:

```
 $("#testtable").tablesorter( {debug:false} );
```

The JS kicks in before the PHP code has had time to populate the fields with data, so the error was displayed. Easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by downloading version 2.15.5 from [here](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#Download).