# IE JavaScript "Message From Webpage" Errors, "Checking If Value was Empty.."

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, tablesorter

I've built an internal webpage that on Firefox is running fine with no issues, but on IE is throwing a load of "Message from webpage" errors.

They are as follows:

- Built headers:,0ms
- [object Object]
- Checking if value was empty on row:0 (several times)
- column:0 parser:text column:1 parser:digit column:2 parser:digit column:3 parser:digit column:4 parser:digit
- Building cache for 5 rows:,0ms

So, a) why are these popping up on IE and b) Is there a way of stopping these from popping up on IE?

Comment: sounds like microsoft sticking its nose in...

Comment: @imulsion I had sussed that already, but need to force them to keep their noses out!

Comment: how true, I love microsoft...except for when they do that ;)

Comment: Same Errors as this [StackOverFlow Question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889232/tablesorter-jquery-plugin-fails-in-ff-3-6-12-with-msg-table-config-parsersc-i)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is from javascript.
Do you have a tablesorter or something similar?

I had the same problem.

if you have something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("table").tablesorter({debug: true}); -> Set this value to False
});
</script>
```

It worked for me.